# Bootstrap grid doesn't fit in my main container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm sure of the fact that I'm doing something so wrong, I tried to solve that this morning.

Here's the deal, I'm trying to build a responsive HTML page, that will have the behaviour of the picture you see below :

[image]

So I told myself, for the elements that have to be move like the elements below "Besoin d'un devis", etc, I will use a the boostrap grid, and use for that an WYSIWIG generator. But instead, when I try to resize the window here's what happens :

**Without resizing the window - Normal behaviour :**

[image]

**When I resize the window and I try to test the boostrap grid :**

[image]

I uploaded a test version in the internet so you can see my problem.
http://test-stackoverflow.co.nf

If you need the code, I will provide it. I just don't know a way to provide a whole "test website" and a case like this in stack.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you used class `container` instead of `container-fluid` in line 110. `container` has a fixed width, when you decrease your browser width, it stays the same and overflows its parent element. `container-fluid` has a width of 100%, so it fills your parent element. 
Then you also have to adapt the images to 100% width (relative to the col-3) and a appropriate height.

**EDIT:**
`.container` has not a fixed width, but your `.container-main#` starts shrinking immediately because of its relative width, while .container shrinks not until your browser window hits 1200px width or less.

Comment: I used a generator ( web generator ) to generate the bootstrap grid..this is why I didn't know that there was a problem with container class..

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div class="content_block orange size_2"> 
<div class="icon fa fa-car"></div>
<div class="text">Auto</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
<div class="content_block rose size_2"> 
<div class="icon fa fa-home"></div>
<div class="text">Habitation</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3">
<div class="content_block green size_2"> 
<div class="icon fa fa-heart"></div>
<div class="text">Santé</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-3"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Try this out

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are overwriting Bootstrap's grid system here:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="content_block orange size_2"> 
                        <div class="icon fa fa-car"></div>
                        <div class="text">Auto</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="content_block rose size_2"> 
                        <div class="icon fa fa-home"></div>
                        <div class="text">Habitation</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-3">
                    <div class="content_block green size_2"> 
                        <div class="icon fa fa-heart"></div>
                        <div class="text">Santé</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-lg-3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So, the columns are set, but then your size-2 style here:

```
.content_block.size_2 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 280px;
}
```

will overwrite that column's width.

Remove the width styling and it should work as intended.  Please comment if additional help is needed.

Comment: Yes, but then in that case the squares will look like this : 
http://upload.dinhosting.fr/E/B/h/Capture2.PNG ..

Comment: Did you remove the height styling?

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry my bad.
I retried the thing now and still doesn't work..I really don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: Instead of the <section class="content_main1"> - try using bootstrap friendly markup: <div class="container-fluid"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"></div></div></div>

Try wrapping it like that, let me know what happens.

Comment: Add any border-styling to the third level.  I.E.: div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 border-style">

Answer (score 0):

Your `.container` class is set to 970px. Set it to 100%. Also change the `.col-sm-3` to `.col-sm-4`. Why? Well you 3 items, grid systems exist out of 12, 12/3 = 4.

Also set the width of the image to 100% to prevent overlapping.

Comment: If I modify my .container class, I think I will delete the bootrap grid behaviour..Am I wrong ?

Comment: You could make your own `.container`class, then you are overriding those attributes. You also could make an other class named `.special` or something and set `width`to a 100%.

Comment: I did what you suggested now, but still, I have the same result.

Comment: You don't even need `.container` if you're going to set the width to 100% - a `div` will do that by default if it's still set to `display: block`.